# select & update in both live & archive tables in the same schema

Tags: oracle, archive, large-data

The application that I am working on currently has an archive logic where all the records older than 6 months will be moved to history tables in the same schema, but on a different table space. This is achieved using a stored procedure which is being executed daily.

For ex. TABLE_A (live, latest 6 months) ==> TABLE_A_H (archive, older than 6 months, up to 8 years).

So far no issues. Now the business has come up with a new requirement where the archived data should also be available for selects & updates. The updates can happen even for an year old data.

selects could be direct like,

select * from TABLE_A where id = 'something'

Or it could be open-ended query like,

select * from TABLE_A where created_date < 'XYZ'

Updates are usually for specific records.

These queries are exposed as REST services to the clients. There are possibilities of junk/null values (no way the application can sanitize the input).

The current snapshot of the DB is

PARENT_TABLE (10M records, 10-15K for each record)
CHILD_TABLE_ONE (28M records, less than 1K for each record)
CHILD_TABLE_TWO (25M records, less than 1K for each record)
CHILD_TABLE_THREE (46M records, less than 1K for each record)
CHILD_TABLE_FOUR (57M records, less than 1K for each record)

Memory is not a constraint - I can procure additional 2 TB of space if needed.
The problem is how do I keep the response time lower when it accesses the archive tables?.
What are all the aspects that I should consider when building a solution?

Solution1: For direct select/update, check if the records are available in live tables. If present, perform the operation on the live tables. If not, perform the operation on the archive tables.

For open ended queries, use UNION ???

Solution2: Use month-wise partitions and keep all 8 years of data in single set of tables?. Does oracle handles 150+ Millions of records in single table for select/update efficiently?

Solution3: Use NoSQL like Couchbase?. Not a feasible solution at the moment because of the infra/cost involved.

Solution4: ???

Tech Stack: Oracle 11G, J2EE Application using Spring/Hibernate (Java 1.6) hosted on JBoss.

Your response will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd go with Solution 2, and ensure that you have the relevant indexes available for the types of queries you expect to be run.

Partitioning by month means that you can take advantage of partition pruning, assuming that the queries involve the column that's being partitioned on.

It also means that your existing code does not need to be amended in order to select or update the archived data.

You'll have to set up housekeeping to add new partitions though - unless you go for interval partitioning, but that has its own set of gotchas.

Comment: Thanks @Boneist. The partitioning will be based on the date column. Most of the queries from the application will not be based on the date column. I could not get enough information on how the partitions are selected. Can you shed some light on this?.

Comment: For ex. I query the DB based on the Location_Code (one of the columns in table) and the partitions are based on Created_On column. How the table will be parsed for the specific Location_Code?. Will it start parsing from the latest partition all the way up to the oldest partition?

Comment: If you don't have an index on the location_code column and you don't have any other predicate that's able to do partition pruning, then the database has no option but to do a full table scan. You need to research partitioning and particularly global vs local partitioned indexes, look at the types of queries you expect to run against your table, and then decide the best inexes you need to add.

Comment: Thanks @boneist. I will research more on the partitioned index. Looks like that's what I will end up with.